Sharing Renv project with library, collaborator still needs to install?
I create a project, get all the packages downloaded and the lock file up to date etc. Everything is working lovely in this directory.
If I then copy the whole project folder over (which should include all the package as there is a local library to the project?), Renv seems to be unaware of these local files and forces the user to redownload everything. It's not that much of a problem as the lockfile appears to be ensuring that the same versions are coming down, but I'd expect it to use the local versions that already came with the project.
When the "new" project starts all packages are missing their description files and I get "One or more packages recorded in the lockfile are not installed".
I then run restore() and it brings everything back.
Then I run library(...) and most (not all weirdly) packages require installing again "Error in library(feasts) : there is no package called ‘feasts’".
When I'm sharing like this, is the expectation that I delete renv/library and renv/staging before it's shared or is there a way to send the libraries with it?
Additionally after running restore() should I need to run renv::install()?
I have read the documentation but clearly haven't understood.

answer contained here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790950/renv-paths-empty-libraries-when-sharing-r-project-which-uses-renv-package?rq=2
